# How to search for a strings from the list of strings

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have the below list of strings

```
List A = {"1","2","3"}

List B = {
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
"1,2,6,7",
"1",
"4,5,6",
"6,7"
}
```

I want to get all the items in List B that completely or partially matches with List A

That is I want to output

```
Result = {
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
"1,2,6,7",
"1"
}
```

How to do this with Linq?

Comment: "Partially matches" means what exactly?

Comment: you see "1,2,6,7" is part of our output, though our input is only {"1","2","3"}.. that is, we are not worried about 6 and 7 coming up in our "1,2,6,7"..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert each comma-separated string into a collection and see if that collection has any items in common with your list `A`. This is easy to do with LINQ:

```
var matches = B.Where(s => s.Split(',').Intersect(A).Any()).ToList();
```

In English:

> Find those strings in `B` that (after being split) have at least one
>   item in common with `A`, and make a list of the results.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/oDUYMY)**.

Note that if the total number of items in `A` and `B` put together is substantial this method will not be very efficient. You can improve the situation by pre-processing `A` into a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and rewriting the filter as

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(A);
var matches = B.Where(s => s.Split(',').Any(n => set.Contains(n))).ToList();
```

This version [produces the same results](http://ideone.com/8UasLj) and will be much faster for large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

What you wants is something like this

```
            string[] A = { "1", "2", "3" };

            string[] B = { "1,2,3,4,5,6,7", "1,2,6,7", "1", "4,5,6", "6,7"};

            var Result = from string S in B
                         where A.Any(i => S.Contains(i))
                         select S;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Contains method,

var Result = new List();

A.ForEach(a => { Result.AddRange( B.Where(b => b.Contains(a))); });

Comment: This will fail once you start getting into double digits.